# Shorthand way of adding strings from class into List<string>?

Tags: c#, list

I have the following C# code:

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
if (myObject.myClass != null)
{
     foreach (var foo in myObject.myClass.subClass)
     {
          names.Add(foo.Name);
     }
}
```

Is there a shorter way of writing this without the need to iterate through each instance of `subClass` to add `myObject.myClass.subClass.Name` into the `names` `List<string>` object?

Also baring in mind `myObject.myClass` can be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you could use:

```
List<string> names = myObject.myClass == null
    ? new List<string>()
    : myObject.myClass.subclass.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Note that this expression: `myObject.myClass.subclass` suggests you're violating the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) fairly nastily - and I *hope* the naming doesn't actually reflect reality though... if you could provide a more indicative set of expressions, that would help a lot.

Comment: +1 Spot on, thanks Jon! And thanks for the link, I wasn't aware this was bad practice. So in this instance, should `subClass` only be visible to `myClass`? So I would have to create an instance of this object to create this `List` such as `var obj = myObject.myClass`. Then use `obj.subClass.Select(...`? Regarding the variable names, these are purely examples

Comment: @Curt: It depends - my guess is that your use of the term "subClass" is actually not what you really mean. It *may* be that it's entirely okay in this case - but without a representative example, it's hard to say.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `AddRange` method to add all elements of an `IEnumerable` to a list:

```
if (myObject.myClass != null) {
    names.AddRange(myObject.myClass.subClass.Select(c => c.Name));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method on List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to build the list, but be aware, it is still enumerating in order to build up the list:

```
var names = myObject.myClass.subClass.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is a collection and what is not. So i assume that `myObject.myClass` is already a collection(`IEnumerable<myClass>`) and can be null and `myClass.subClass` is an `IEnumerable<subClass>` and you want all of their names.

```
var classNames = from c in myObject.myClass
                 where c != null
                 from subC in c.subClass
                 where subC != null
                 select subC.Name;
List<String> names = classNames.ToList();
```

This is a LINQ query, it's the equivalent of [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx) in method syntax.

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq`.